# Remove all rows from an Advanced Custom Field Repeater (frontend, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

We have a repeater field on our WordPress website that can display hundreds of rows of data, these can all be imported in via copy and paste, that auto generates the rows. If we want to re-import this data, we would have to remove the existing rows first beforehand. There may also be scenarios we want to remove all data to start from scratch. However, ACF doesn't provide the option to remove all rows from a repeater in one simple frontend action. There is the option to remove each one one by one, however this is time consuming. The PHP method isn't also viable, as it doesn't provide immediate feedback from a UI perspective.

I've visited [ACF's JavaScript API page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/javascript-api/#acf.field-remove) and scrolled down to "remove field.remove()". This states that it "removes the field from the DOM and unregisters all assigned events, actions and filters". I have attempted to test this by adding a simple global JavaScript function that loops through the repeater field rows, and then remove them one by one:

```
function removeAllRepeaterFields() {
    jQuery(".acf-repeater > .acf-table > tbody > tr.acf-row:not(.acf-clone)").each(function( index, element ) {
        var id = element.dataset.id;
        var field = acf.getField('field_' + id);
        if ( field ) {
            field.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

However when I try this in the browser's console, nothing happens. Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more tweaking, I've discovered that you don't need to use ACF's JS API to remove them, you simply just need to remove the entire  element; once you click the Save/Update button, the removed fields are taken into consideration, and updated accordingly. Therefore the function in the question becomes the following:

```
function removeAllRepeaterFields() {
    jQuery(".acf-repeater > .acf-table > tbody > tr.acf-row:not(.acf-clone)").each(function( index, element ) {
        element.remove();
    });
}
```

The documentation requires updating to mention this.

Comment: And if you have multiple repeaters on the page, replace .acf-repeater with .acf-field-61a6d530e5912 (or whatever) so you empty just the one you want.

Comment: Indeed @Chad Phillips - I only have one repeater on the page, but I'm developing a plugin that will add a dedicated button against each repeater that will delete all the rows against that associated repeater.

Comment: Nice!  Please add to the WordPress repo and reply back with the name whenever it's ready.  I might need that one day.